# single browse button to upload multiple images (smarty)

Tags: php, html

how can I let the user upload multiple files in a certain dictionary with one browse button?

I have heard and read some articles that you can do it with jquery + flash etc..

but what I am looking for is plain php and html that can work on smarty template!

Is it possible to do it? examples? articles? any help well be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at this: http://davidwalsh.name/multiple-file-upload

The article is rather old (2010), so chances are more browsers have this feature now (like IE9). You could take it for a testride with the different browsers you want to support.

Comment: the example that you have given uses jquery :/ which I despise

Comment: Check one more time, it does not use jQuery.

Comment: Sorry I followed the wrong link. the link that you have given me is useful, but it does not explain how to submit those images and upload them into a certain dictionary

Comment: Simply googling `php file upload` will give you the answer to that. You should look at the examplecode, it foreaches all the files the user tried to upload, so you can upload them and do whatever you want one file a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multiple attribute with the input element with a type of file.

Something like this will work:

```
<input name='uploads[]' type="file" multiple>
```

Comment: when somebody click on the submit button, how can I seperate them and put them on seperate? does the first file gets name="uploads[1]' and the second gets name="upload[2]" or what? I want each file to get a seperate name

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php for how to handle the PHP side of it